# Determine maximum storage capacity for handling bitmaps for display in UWP App

Tags: memory-management, uwp

I am shuffling hundreds of bitmaps into and out of RAM as my users browse through their asset library. There is a maximum storage space for bitmaps. Right now, doing the conservative thing, I am dumping all loaded bitmaps when the asset view changes (think of a page flip etc.).

This results in rather jarring delays in the fetch/render cycles, even if the asset was already loaded in the last page.

I am now wondering how I could **write a cache** that would retain some bitmaps in memory, releasing them on timeout or when they are explicitly dropped by the app.

I am using assets from multiple sources, including local disk and network URIs..., so simply using the XAML  mechanisms won't work (as that only is applicable for network URIs, not local assets).

To do that, I would need to know, **how much memory the app actually has to work with for bitmaps**. *Is there any way to find out at runtime???*

Comment: I think it might be better to control the image source. No matter where you get these images, you need to read or download them in your memory. In the beginning, just load part of them into memory, you could show them in your UI first. Then read and download the next part if needed. And remember to release the pervious part at the same time you load new images.

Comment: Oh I know, the question is how to swapping in and out of memory can be optimized so that I reload the least amount of bitmaps without OutOfMemory or similar misbehavior...

Comment: If I understand @RoyLi-MSFT suggestion correctly, there shouldn't be out of memory issue if you just show part of them at one time.

Comment: If you cut the image list into small parts and show them one by one and release the previous image on time, will you still get the outofmemory exception? If this works, then you don't need to modify the memory.

Comment: Gentlemen, please read my question. Of course I am paging through assets. My question is how to determine when I HAVE to release a bitmap from memory (to be loaded again later), because with asset sizes in the 100MB range each, that is a bit laggy. So, how can I find out when the UWP container reaches its capacity and it is time to clean cache?

Comment: No way to check that. That's why you need to cut your image sources into pieces.

Comment: Anybody from MSFT please confirm? The UWP container does not provide any metrics on mem usage for these kinds of circumstance?

Comment: Like @Anonymous said, there is no API that could check the memory used by bitmpas